# How to get colored error message when use gcc in makefile?

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile

Gcc output colored error message and warning message on OS X when use it in the shell, but when use it in makefile, the output message is monochrome.

How to get colored message when use gcc in makefile?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
-fdiagnostics-color=always
```

to your gcc invocation in your Makefile.